# How to map properties of two different objects?

Tags: c#, oop, object

I want to know how to map fields of two different objects and assign the values to it.

Eample:

```
public class employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class manager
{
    public int MgrId { get; set; }
    public string MgrName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a List object. I want to assign the values to "manager" class. Any automatic way to do that. I can do it explicitly and assigning values to it. But my object is very huge thats the problem. I dont want to use any third party tools too.

**Note: It can't have any prefix for manager. It can be anything. (Ex: mgrId can be like mgrCode)**

Comment: *"I dont want to use any third party tools too."* Why not?

Comment: Use reflection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx

Comment: Just a suggestion: http://automapper.org/ , its a great tool to convert objects like this.

Comment: What's the source you use for assigning values to the manager class?

Comment: _(...)mgrId can be like mgrCode(...)_, at some point, you'll need to provide some kind of mapping...

Comment: Right... Whatyou're asking is "I have to objects, with different properties, with possibly no set rule to associate them... is there something that can figure out what I want it to do?"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use reflection for it, even by ignoring the property casing (notice the `employee.ID` vs. `manager.MgrId`):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var employee = new Employee() { ID = 1, Name = "John" };
        var manager = new Manager();
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(Employee).GetProperties())
        {
            typeof(Manager)
                .GetProperty("Mgr" + propertyInfo.Name,
                    BindingFlags.IgnoreCase |
                    BindingFlags.Instance |
                    BindingFlags.Public)
                .SetValue(manager,
                    propertyInfo.GetValue(employee));
        }
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Manager
{
    public int MgrId { get; set; }
    public string MgrName { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't know the `Mgr` prefix, you could only match by suffixes:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(Employee).GetProperties())
{
    typeof(Manager).GetMembers()
        .OfType<PropertyInfo>()
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.EndsWith(propertyInfo.Name, 
            StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        .SetValue(manager,
            propertyInfo.GetValue(employee));
}
```

And **a very narrow and impractical assumption**: mapping based on the property order (if you are expecting the 2 types to have properties defined in the same sequence and number, the only difference being the property names). I wouldn't recommend anyone using it in real life, but still, here it is (just to make it more *fragile* :) ):

```
typeof(Employee)
    .GetProperties()
    .Select((p, index) =>
        new { Index = index, PropertyInfo = p })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(p =>
        {
            typeof(Manager)
                .GetProperties()
                .Skip(p.Index)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .SetValue(manager,
                    p.PropertyInfo.GetValue(employee));
        });
```

Comment: There's an overload of [`PropertyInfo.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385.aspx) that takes the source object. There is also a two argument overload of [`PropertyInfo.SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291.aspx).

Comment: Correct, starting with 4.5. I was compiling with 3.5 :) I'll update my answer.

Comment: I guess I've been using .Net 4.5 a lot lately.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici Do the properties have to be the same type, or is there a way to convert them?

Answer (score 13):

Use reflection or [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). I recommend the latter since writing new code is wasteful if it doesn't have a purpose.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Manager
{
    public int MgrId { get; set; }
    public string MgrName { get; set; }
}

Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
   cfg.RecognizeDestinationPrefixes("Mgr");
   cfg.CreateMap<Employee, Manager>();
});

var manager = Mapper.Map<Employee, Manager>(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Fred" });

Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}", manager.MgrId);
Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", manager.MgrName);
```

If the properties don't have an idiomatic source identifier then use AutoMapper's [projection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection).

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, Manager>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.MgrCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ID))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.MgrName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
```

Comment: Does it ignore the property casing?

Comment: Yes it will ignore property casing.

Comment: But here i need to use automapper. Is there any way like serialization?

Comment: Serialization is completely different. There is reflection which the answer below demonstrated, but the code is cumbersome and fragile. Using third party code is the norm in the managed world since the code is tested and it works. Just use [NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/2.2.1) and install it. It's painless and simple.

Comment: OK I will try to Change the properties in a meaningful way and i will use the reflection. That is the only way to do it. How the typed dataset mapping works? Do you have any idea on that? I am expecting such kind of way only.

Comment: That is probably better suited as a different question. Be sure to accept an answer if one of the solutions works for you.

Comment: sure man thanks a lot. I will experiment it and will accept it. I will raise it as a different question.

Comment: @Romoku, does mapper ignore type? Or have a way to covert the type?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is kind old now but for other people who are looking for answer is this what you can go for.. just simply use lambda expression

```
var managers = employees.Select(x => new Manager()
{
    MgrCode = x.ID,
    MgrName = x.Name
}).ToList();
```

Comment: supposing `Manager()` has more than 2 properties, your solution would mean that the person has to manually type and assign all the properties, which is usually tedious.